Why is my boolean cut so messy?
I'm wondering what the best way to clean up my geometry from a boolean cut would be.  Or if using the boolean modifier is even the best way to go about receiving the results I'm looking for.
I modeled some specific shapes to use as cutting tools to be applied to the outsole of my shoe model.  As you can see in the images below, the cutting tools are organic shapes with beveled edges on the inside to make a cleaner, more of a 90 deg. cut.  The cuts are the approximate shape I'm looking for, but I'm getting bad shading on all the cuts except for one for some reason.  The one that's clean had it's normal flipped originally, but I had since corrected it.
I need the boolean on both the bottom and the sides and thought it would be easier to just do two separate boolean cuts.  I tried applying the subdiv surf modifier to both the outsole and the cutting tool before applying the boolean modifier and it did not help.  I cntrl Z and none of the modifiers are currently applied.



I flipped the normals of all the objects that were to be cut into, and that cleaned things up, but it made them hollow, so I'll just have to fill them after applying the subdiv surf and boolean modifier
